Python: Binarized 2D sequential tif images into 3D image which can be rotate by drag
Until a few years ago, 2D CT image (black and white) could be stacked with the code below.
import imageio.v2 as imageio
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pyvista as pv

all = np.stack([
imageio.imread("dataset_{:02d}.tif".format(n)) > 100
for n in range(30) ], axis=0)

image3d = pv.Plotter(notebook=False)
image3d.add_mesh(...)
image3d.show([pv.VoxelData(pict).threshold("value", (0.5, 1.0))], wait=False)

pv.show([pv.VoxelData(pict).threshold("value", (0.5, 1.0))], wait=False)

This gave us the 3D image and we could rotate freely with drag. However, recently, the Error says "NotImplementedError: Unable to wrap (<class 'ellipsis'>) into a pyvista type". "AttributeError: module 'pyvista' has no attribute 'UniformGrid'". I don't know what I should do...
Since I don't want to go back to former version, I want do the same thing with newest version of python. DO you know how to do this? I'm sorry I couldn't find sample sequence tif figures which are the slices of 3D image on the internet. (I found most downloadable figures are too many files.)
I also tried another code using homcloud package,
import pyvista as pv
import homcloud.pyvistahelper as pvhelper
pv.set_jupyter_backend('trame')
pl = pv.Plotter()

pl.add_mesh(pvhelper.Bitmap3D(pict).threshold(0.4), 
show_scalar_bar=False, opacity=0.8)

But this time the Error was "AttributeError: module 'pyvista' has no attribute 'UniformGrid'".
Here I tried with simple code as below, but it did not work either.
import numpy as np
import plotly.graph_objects as go

data = np.random.rand(100, 100, 100)  
x, y, z = np.indices(data.shape)
values = data.flatten()

mask = values > 0.5
x, y, z = x[mask], y[mask], z[mask]

fig = go.Figure(data=go.Scatter3d(
x=x,
y=y,
z=z,
mode='markers',
marker=dict(size=2, color='blue', opacity=0.5)
))

fig.update_layout(scene=dict(
xaxis_title='X-axis',
yaxis_title='Y-axis',
zaxis_title='Z-axis'
))

fig.show()

Could you help me??

"did not work" is insufficient. what's the error message? [ask], [mre]

Oh, I'm sorry. The way of asking was not good. For the simple code, it seems the dimension setting is no good. The error code is "IndexError: boolean index did not match indexed array along dimension 0; dimension is 100 but corresponding boolean dimension is 1000000".

And the Error for the upper code (stacking data set) says "NotImplementedError: Unable to wrap (<class 'ellipsis'>) into a pyvista type". "AttributeError: module 'pyvista' has no attribute 'UniformGrid'".

Your last comment's error comes from literally having image3d.add_mesh(...) in your code, as above...

As for UniformGrid: it's been renamed to ImageData. But don't comment with additional details, [edit] your question instead.

Thank you for telling me. This is second time for me to ask question in stackoverflow, and I'm sorry I didn't know much about the manner here...

Thanks for the edit. Your first code block still makes no sense. That couldn't have been your original working code. Find your actual code if you want it debugged.
